# Getting this line continuously in terminal "[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with npm...". , when run ionic project

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm setting up an Ionic project with all the necessary dependencies. However, when I run the command "ionic serve", I encounter a continuous display of the line "[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with npm...'.in the terminal. This prevents me from successfully running the project.

Here's the relevant portion of my terminal output:

```
npm.cmd run ionic:serve:before

wyres@0.0.1 ionic:serve:before
gulp

Using gulpfile E:\NishantDataIonic\Moodle IOS\Moodle\gulpfile.js
Starting 'default'...
Starting 'lang'...
Starting 'env'...
Finished 'env' after 214 ms
Finished 'lang' after 1.04 s
Finished 'default' after 1.04 s
> npm.cmd run ionic:serve -- --host=localhost --port=8100
[npm] > wyres@0.0.1 ionic:serve
[npm] > gulp watch & NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096 ng serve --host=localhost --port=8100
[npm] [12:42:57] Using gulpfile E:\NishantDataIonic\Moodle IOS\Moodle\gulpfile.js
[npm] [12:42:57] Starting 'watch'...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with npm...
```

Here's my Ionic environment information:

```
Ionic:

Ionic CLI : 5.4.16 (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 5.0.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 15.2.8
@angular-devkit/schematics : 15.2.8
@angular/cli : 15.2.8
@ionic/angular-toolkit : 6.0.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI : 10.0.0 (cordova-lib@10.1.0)
Cordova Platforms : not available
Cordova Plugins : not available

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.15.4
native-run : 1.7.2

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
NodeJS : v16.14.2 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm : 9.5.0
OS : Windows 10
```

I've already tried changing my Node version to 16 from 14 and adjusted dependencies accordingly. I've also installed the Angular and Ionic extensions in VS Code.
I'm seeking assistance in resolving this issue so that I can successfully run my Ionic project. Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my packege.json file

```
{
  "name": "wyres",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "The official app for WY RES.",
  "author": {
    "name": "Moodle Pty Ltd.",
    "email": "mobile@moodle.com"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/moodlehq/moodlemobile2.git"
  },
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "Apache-2.0",
      "url": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"
    }
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ionic serve",
    "build": "ionic build",
    "build:prod": "NODE_ENV=production ionic build --prod",
    "build:test": "NODE_ENV=testing ionic build",
    "dev:android": "ionic cordova run android --livereload",
    "dev:ios": "ionic cordova run ios --livereload",
    "prod:android": "NODE_ENV=production ionic cordova run android --aot",
    "prod:ios": "NODE_ENV=production ionic cordova run ios --aot",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=testing gulp && jest --verbose",
    "test:ci": "NODE_ENV=testing gulp && jest -ci --runInBand --verbose",
    "test:watch": "NODE_ENV=testing gulp watch & jest --watch",
    "test:coverage": "NODE_ENV=testing gulp && jest --coverage",
    "lint": "NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096 ng lint",
    "ionic:serve:before": "gulp",
    "ionic:serve": "gulp watch & NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096 ng serve",
    "ionic:build:before": "gulp"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "15.2.8",
    "@angular/common": "15.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "15.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "15.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "15.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "15.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "15.2.8",
    "@capacitor/android": "5.2.3",
    "@capacitor/app": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/core": "5.2.3",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "5.0.6",
    "@ionic-native/badge": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/chooser": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/clipboard": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/media": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/media-capture": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/push": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/qr-scanner": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/web-intent": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/zip": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.7.5",
    "@ionic/utils-fs": "3.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "6.0.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "2.9.31",
    "@types/cordova": "0.0.34",
    "@types/cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.6.2",
    "@types/dom-mediacapture-record": "1.0.7",
    "chart.js": "2.9.4",
    "com-darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent": "1.3.0",
    "cordova": "10.0.0",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "3.0.1",
    "cordova-clipboard": "1.3.0",
    "cordova-ios": "6.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "3.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-chooser": "1.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "3.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-globalization": "1.11.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-media": "5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-media-capture": "3.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "3.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-zip": "3.1.0",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "6.0.0",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "5.0.2",
    "core-js": "3.9.1",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "4.2.2",
    "jszip": "3.5.0",
    "lru-cache": "7.13.1",
    "mathjax": "2.7.7",
    "moment": "2.29.0",
    "nl.kingsquare.cordova.background-audio": "1.0.1",
    "phonegap-plugin-multidex": "1.0.0",
    "rxjs": "7.4.0",
    "ts-md5": "1.2.7",
    "tslib": "2.0.1",
    "zone.js": "0.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.1101.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "15.2.8",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "15.2.8",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "15.2.8",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "16.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "16.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "16.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "16.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "15.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "15.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "15.2.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "10.0.14",
    "@capacitor/cli": "5.2.3",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "6.0.0",
    "@ionic/cli": "6.4.0",
    "@types/faker": "5.1.3",
    "@types/node": "12.12.64",
    "@types/resize-observer-browser": "0.1.5",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.22.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.22.0",
    "check-es-compat": "1.1.1",
    "cordova-android": "^9.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "git+https://github.com/moodlemobile/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "git+https://github.com/moodlemobile/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git#moodle-ionic5",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "git+https://github.com/moodlemobile/cordova-plugin-local-notification.git#moodle",
    "cordova-plugin-prevent-override": "git+https://github.com/moodlemobile/cordova-plugin-prevent-override.git",
    "cordova-plugin-qrscanner": "git+https://github.com/moodlemobile/cordova-plugin-qrscanner.git#dist",
    "cordova-plugin-wkuserscript": "git+https://github.com/moodlemobile/cordova-plugin-wkuserscript.git",
    "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-cookies": "git+https://github.com/moodlemobile/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-cookies.git",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.2.1",
    "eslint": "7.25.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-header": "3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "24.3.6",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "32.3.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "5.1.0",
    "faker": "5.1.0",
    "fs-extra": "9.1.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-clip-empty-files": "0.1.2",
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.1",
    "gulp-flatten": "0.4.0",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "5.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "2.0.0",
    "gulp-slash": "1.1.3",
    "jest": "29.6.2",
    "jest-preset-angular": "13.1.1",
    "jsonc-parser": "2.3.1",
    "native-run": "^1.4.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-push": "git+https://github.com/moodlemobile/phonegap-plugin-push.git#moodle-v3",
    "ts-jest": "29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "8.3.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "npm": "9.5.0",
    "node": "v16.14.2"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "platforms": [
      "ios"
    ],
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {},
      "cordova-clipboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-badge": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-chooser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme": {
        "URL_SCHEME": "moodlemobile",
        "ANDROID_SCHEME": " ",
        "ANDROID_HOST": " ",
        "ANDROID_PATHPREFIX": "/"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GPS_REQUIRED": "false"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "26.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-media-capture": {},
      "cordova-plugin-media": {
        "KEEP_AVAUDIOSESSION_ALWAYS_ACTIVE": "NO"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-qrscanner": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-wkuserscript": {},
      "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-cookies": {},
      "cordova-plugin-zip": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-push": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V13_VERSION": "27.+",
        "FCM_VERSION": "17.0.+"
      },
      "com-darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent": {},
      "nl.kingsquare.cordova.background-audio": {},
      "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "28.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-globalization": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-prevent-override": {}
    }
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "keytar": "7.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

first step, could you try to update your ionic version ? Angular 15+ required ionic 6.3+

| ionic V | Min Ng Version | Max Ng Version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| v7 | v14 | v16+ |
| v6 | v12 | v15 |
| v5 | v8.2 | v12 |

Angular 14.x supported starting in Ionic v6.1.9. Angular 15.x supported starting in Ionic v6.3.6.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/reference/support#ionic-angular

You can find on the ionic documentation, update guides if needed

Comment: I have updated ionic framework from 5 to 6 but still same issue.

Comment: Try this "ng serve --port=8100" instead of ionic serve

Comment: This command "ng serve --port=8100" gives error as :

Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(stylePreprocessorOptions).
E:\IonicProj\Moodle IOS\Moodle\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\hostReportError.js:4
    setTimeout(function () { throw err; }, 0);

Comment: Although there is -1 to my answer, I remain convinced that it is a version problem. Can we see your package.json?